# WPF ViewModel changes not updated for child controls contained in a parent control with datacontext set

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have two stackpanels, one has the datacontext set and the child controls within it are bound to the properties of the object.  The second stackpanel has no databinding, but the child controls reference the object and property.

When updating the object in the viewmodel, the changes made to the firstname and lastname are shown in the second stackpanel, but nothing changes in the first, and I don't understand why?  Does anyone have any advice on why this would be given that when the application is first loaded, the correct details are displayed in both panels, the problem only occurs when a change is made via the viewmodel.

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Person}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBox>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Commands.Update, ElementName=mainView}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0 0 0 20">Update</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.LastName}"></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Attached is a copy of the entire solution that demonstrates the problem can be found [here](http://1drv.ms/1THg3Ri).

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: could you show us the viewmodel too?

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to add link, which I have now added.

Comment: I've inspected your code - your `Person` class should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and its `FirstName` and `LastName` properties should raise the `PropertyChanged` event. I think that correcting this should resolve your problem.

Comment: @Grx70 - that has done the trick and works perfectly - Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I made an XAML like this :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Person}"  >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"  ></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" ></TextBox>
                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.Commands.Update, ElementName=mainView}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="75">Update</Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.LastName}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in the code behind I made this :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new MainViewModel()
            {
                Person = new Person() { FirstName = "Bruce", LastName = "Lee" }
            };
        }
    }
```

and..it works !

this is the MainViewModel :

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private Person person;
        public Person Person
        {
            get { return person; }
            set
            {
                if (person != value)
                {
                    person = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Person");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then , this is the person class

```
public class Person : ViewModelBase
{
    private string lastName;
    public string LastName 
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set
        {
            if (lastName != value)
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
    }

    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (firstName != value)
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: But where/when do you make changes to `FirstName` and/or `LastName` (that's the part that OP has problem with)?

Comment: You cannot make changes to FirstName from the UI, because its  a TextBlock, but from the ViewModel you can change it. (in other term it's Binding is OneWay..I'll give you the MainViewModel and the Person classes